# copyrights text over an image is getting messed up in html

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an HTML where I need to add copyrights text at the bottom of the page but I need to add that text on another image. Here is my div which I added:

```
<div class="copy-rights">
    <img src="https://s30.postimg.org/ws4b9bff5/copyrights.png" />
    <p>
        ©THE NORTHMAN COMPANY . 2017 . ALL RIGHTS RESERVED
    </p>
</div>
```

I have created this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g2ahx6nq/23/) in which I have added `copy-rights div` at the bottom of the page but somehow in my jsfiddle I see lot of white spaces between my `copyrights div` and the bottom page so I am not able to put an image first and then copyrights text on top of it properly.

My `copy-rights` div is getting messed up and that copyrights image is also messed up in my jsfiddle.

Technically it should be like this: https://s12.postimg.org/s70kwke59/copyright-image.png

What wrong I have done?

Comment: instead of using <img> i suggest you might want to use background-image which might solve your problem

Comment: what's the point of the image? just to give the text a background color?

Comment: yeah I think so.. I want to replicate it as it is so that's why I have to do it.. Put image first and then text on top of it.

Comment: It's a very bad way to code and not taking in account responsiveness. For learning purposes, this is a good way to get familiar with HTML-tags, but you really need to improve

Comment: @ThomasvanBroekhoven yeah I know and I am still learning.. As of now my jsfiddle is messed up because of absolute width issues I believe. And that is why alignments are getting messed up and all my divs are messed up too. If someone can help me understand how we can fix that then I will be able to learn on how to tackle these kind of problems.

Comment: Try to use as little absolute positioning as possible. Try to make divs with float and build up layouts from top to bottom. It's not very hard, but try to see how other websites are doing it

Comment: sure will do some research. If you can provide examples on my jsfiddle then it will help me get an idea quicker and understand the solution fast. It will help me to grasp the concept quickly I believe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seemed to be many mistakes in your code that were throwing out the layout.
When i amended the errors, the `background` was gray in parts and black in others. If this was not what you are aiming for, it should be easy enough to change now.

I didn't fix everything, but i did a few things. Your `footer` issue fixed anyway. There seems to be a problem in the left sidebar that was happened while other things fell into place. I'm sure you can fix it with a bit of `margin-top` or something, I didn't look at it closely.

Do review the changes in the css. You've said you're a beginner; it's a good way to learn.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/3xt32zsf/)

Happy coding!

EDIT: [Yaha!](https://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/07u2j3Lo/) (fix i took out top/left/bottom etc positions and some padding) still might need a tweak til you're happy with it.. [Preview](https://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/07u2j3Lo/embedded/result/)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. It looks like in your latest [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/07u2j3Lo/) everything went upside down. Technically my html should look like this [image](https://s12.postimg.org/4xtgnby3h/0-nav-open.png) but somehow in my jsfiddle it's not getting shown as that image so looks like I did something wrong. And since I am beginner it will help me to learn if someone can help me with an example to see how we can exactly make my fiddle as compared to that image.

Comment: I am having hard time to fix the alignment issue to make exactly similar as the image I have.

Comment: This is my latest [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g2ahx6nq/29/) which is trying to replicate that image. And this doesn't have your changes for copyright. Any thoughts how can I fix my alignment and match it exactly with that image and fix copyrights as well?

Comment: @david it's 6:30am Irish time and I've just seen your comments, the ones left 3 hours ago. If you had examined the corrections to your CSS, you may have been [well] able to fix your code. SO is not a code writing service, nor is it my full time job. If you accept the answer I may look at your picture later. Advice: ask a new question. (Or learn.some CSS  from posted answer!)

Answer (score 0):

Paudel is right you can just set background: grey; and it will look the same.

Otherwise you will need to set wrapped div to be relative and the text element absolute. Something like:

```
.content { 
   position: relative; 
   width: 100%; /* for IE 6 */
}

h2 { 
   position: absolute; 
   top: 200px; 
   left: 0; 
   width: 100%; 
}
```

Regards

Comment: can you provide jsfiddle so that I can understand better on how it will be done?

Comment: Hope i understand right what you are looking for:
https://jsfiddle.net/g2ahx6nq/26/

Comment: yeah I also got this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g2ahx6nq/25/) created . As you can see it is going out of alignment.. How can we fix that as well? It has to be exactly similar to the other image I have.

Comment: what you think now ?
https://jsfiddle.net/g2ahx6nq/28/

May be need     margin-left: 35px; to copy-rights element

Answer (score 0):

Make the picture a background-image

HTML:

```
<div class="copy-rights"> 
  <p>
    ©THE NORTHMAN COMPANY . 2017 . ALL RIGHTS RESERVED 
  </p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.copy-rights {
  background-image: url('https://s30.postimg.org/ws4b9bff5/copyrights.png');
}
```

**Update:**

Since the image is just a grey area, background color can be applied as well:

```
.copy-rights {
  background-color: grey;
}
```

Comment: yeah I added that and created another [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g2ahx6nq/25/) as well. As you can see it is all messed up. How can I make it exactly like my other image I have?

Comment: It's because it's repeating the image. You can use `background-repeat: none;` and `background-position: bottom;`, but as I mentioned in an earlier comment, your code is messed up.. sorry

Comment: I tried that and still it doesnt work. I think its happening bcoz of absolute width issues on all my html. It's all over my jsfiddle. Any thoughts on how to fix that?